# Angular: $scope properties updated with $timeout doesn't seem to update DOM in order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on some kind of notification system for geolocation functionality, using Angular.

Response message depends on *HTML5 Geolocation API* result: *success* or *error*, where *error* includes three states (*permission denied*, *position unavailable* and *position calculation timeout*).

Once *success* or *error* function got a response, Angular should change two properties in the scope: *isLoading* and *loaderType*. The first one is used for handling loader display state and the second one for displaying response alert.

Here's a code snippet:

```
$scope.loaderType = 'success';

$timeout(function() {
  $scope.isLoading = false;
}, 2000);
```

On success loader type should change to *success* and the loader itself should go out of loading state after 2 second, but it seems like both changes updates DOM after timeout has been reached, while properties itself updates in proper order.

Here's a fiddle with demo: http://jsfiddle.net/roman01la/3r3dr/

Is there some trick with Angular's *$timeout* function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You update $scope outside of angular (inside `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`'s callback), angular is not aware of the update. A correct solution for this is [$scope.$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope). Wrap your code like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
     //All your code here that needs updating $scope.
  });
 });
```

Comment: This is just a code snippet, please, check the fiddle. Everything is inside Angular, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Roman: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`'s callback is not inside angular

Comment: Yep, just figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome note. Thanks. I completely forgot that the navigator.geo call is not $scope'd... Saved me hours of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i think am late..

$timeout([fn], [delay], [invokeApply], [Pass]);

this is definition of the $timeout service in angular the third parameter wrap the function in an $scope.$apply method this is something that angular does by him self, with this the DOM is update and you prevent the  Error: $digest already in progress

```
  $timeout(function() {
              $scope.isLoading = false;
            }, 2000,true);
```

this is the angular documentation
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Answer (score 0):

I was able to diagnose a number of things that weren't working about this code. You can use the watch (and even timeout if you would like) but you need to make sure you watch the correct variable. You aren't interested in watching a string, but rather in watching the value of "$scope.isLoading". So, what you need for the watch line of code in the directive is:

```
$scope.$watch($scope.isLoading, function ($value) {
```

Then, another thing I noticed is you never actually call the "getPosition()" function. That isn't going to ever run if you don't call it. So, add the following line of code to your controller:

```
$scope.getPosition();
```

Finally, there is the matter of apply. As "Khanh TO" said, in directives you actually have to call apply in order to see the change on the screen. There are two ways to do this. The first is to place the code in a function and inject this function into a call to apply (Khanh's approach). The other is to run whatever code you need to, then just call the apply function with no parameters. If you wish to take this approach, just update your call as follows:

```
$scope.isLoading = false;
$scope.$apply();
```

And that should do it! I was able to get a working sample after making these changes. Best of luck!